# Text-shadow density in css to get a blur effect

Tags: css

Is there a better way to give greater density to text-shadow? the only solution that occurred to me is to repeat multiple times the text-shadow on the text, but this is somewhat sloppy. I thinks IE10 supports spread radius, but it is the only one.

```
body{
    background:#000
}
h1 {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family:Arial;
    color: #F90;
    text-shadow: 
        0 0 20px #FFF, 
        0 0 20px #FFF, 
        0 0 20px #FFF, 
        0 0 20px #FFF, 
        0 0 20px #FFF, 
        0 0 20px #FFF, 
        0 0 20px #FFF, 
        0 0 20px #FFF, 
        0 0 20px #FFF, 
        0 0 20px #FFF, 
        0 0 20px #FFF, 
        0 0 20px #FFF, 
        0 0 20px #FFF, 
        0 0 20px #FFF;
}
```

Compare working examples in jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/poselab/jAgF3/3/

http://jsfiddle.net/poselab/pHnTm/

Comment: as far as i know, there is no other ways at this time. You can make a mixed with 1px 1px white, -1px 1px white and so on , to make brighter, but , too much will do some pixelArt :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve @PoseLab but the "blur" attribute on text shadow is supported in most browsers if you check support for this.
[caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/css-textshadow)

by changing the blur up and down from 0 would surely change the density from a solid colour, to a more faded effect.

maybe doing something like

```
text-shadow:2px 2px 0 #fff;
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jAgF3/4/)

hope this helps, you can always play around with a text-shadow generator too.

[CSS3 text shadow generator](http://css3gen.com/text-shadow/)

P.S (i apologize also, Text-shadow is supported in IE9 as well)